# Why are special characters displayed as question marks in Facebook posts?

Tags: facebook, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding, magnolia

When we share links to our magnolia website (running on Tomcat), umlaut characters are displayed as question marks.
The page head has `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and the response header has content type `text/html;charset=UTF-8` and content encoding `gzip`. What could be causing the wrong character encoding on Facebook?

Comment: Probably they _are_ not actually, properly encoded in UTF-8? Just because you _say_ they were via the `Content-Type`, does not automatically _make_ it so.

Comment: @CBroe, how can I check the actual encoding? I exported the JCR-Node of the page and its first line specifies the encoding: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Do you have an actual example URL that shows the problem?

Comment: The Facebook Sharing Debugger generated the following: `curl -v --compressed -H "Range: bytes=0-524288" -H "Connection: close" -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "https://www.mieterverband.ch/mv/politik-positionen/news/2019/Jetzt-w%C3%A4hlen-f%C3%BCr-mieterfreundliche-Mehrheiten-in-Bern.html"`, which yields a response with no content. If I leave out the `Range` field I get the message body. So in the past, when Facebook could crawl the site, the encoding could have been wrong, but now the problem seems to be that Facebook cannot crawl the page.

Comment: Where exactly does it generate this cURL code? Not sure where it would get that byte range from. The URL returns a response containing a header `Content-Length: 12298`, so I don’t see where from anyone could get the idea to request `bytes=0-524288` to begin with.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ 
Thats right, but even though the range is reduced, the message body is still empty

Comment: Then you need to figure out what makes your site react that way. Try and send the same request, but with a User-Agent that indicates a normal browser - any change? If so, it is likely some sort of component/plugin, that tries to block requests by “bad” bots.

Comment: if I leave out the user agent, I still do not get any response body so the problem seems to be related to the range.

Comment: @CBroe, many thanks for the help! I wonder if this question is off-topic according to point 6 of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out, that my problem was not related to the character encoding, but rather the Facebook crawler request. The [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) really got me on track. The core problem was that, the magnolia cache did not support partial requests.

**Edit:**
HTTP range requests from Facebook is a known issue, see https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS62/_Known+issues#id-_Knownissues-HTTPrangerequestsfromFacebookdon%27twork